# Inequality on the expectations of the inverse of random variables

Tags: probability

Given $X$ and $Y$ two positive random variables such that $\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[Y]$ and $\mathbb E\left[X^2\right] > \mathbb E\left[Y^2\right]$ is it true that $\mathbb E\left[\frac1X\right] > \mathbb E\left[\frac1Y\right]$?

Comment: Can you atleast add more context to your question?. Where did you encounter it? What are the ideas you have of showing it? Isolated problems like these attract downvotes and closure.

Comment: Presumably you have tried examples, no?  Could you include some of those?

Comment: Note:  it might help to note that, given that the means coincide, the second condition is equivalent to saying that the variance of $X$ is greater.

Comment: I also noticed that E[X^2] > E[Y^2] implies Var[X]>Var[Y] due to Var[X]=E[X^2]+(E[X])^2. For unimodal distributions, there is a clear graphical intuition for the proposition because the increased variance leads the tails of the distribution to spread out further to the left and right of the expected value. Since 1/x is a convex function for x>0, values to the left of the mean are overemphasized when computing E[1/X]. The statement is easy to verify for many simple distributions like uniform distributions w. different supports, but I am unsure how to approach it for more "ugly" distributions.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independant?

Comment: Thanks for the remark, yes they are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Let $$X\sim 
\begin{cases}
1000, \text{ with probability } 0.5\\
10, \text{ with probability } 0.5
\end{cases}
$$

and $$Y\sim 
\begin{cases}
1000, \text{ with probability } 0.49\\
100, \text{ with probability } 0.49-p\\
1, \text{ with probability } p.
\end{cases}
$$

Then for $p=\frac{34}{99}\approx0.343$, we have $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y],$$ and $$\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] = 1000^2(0.5)+10^2(0.5) >1000^2\left(0.49\right)+100^2\left(0.147\right)+1^2\left(0.343\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[Y^2\right],$$
but
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] <\frac{1}{10}< p < \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{Y}\right].$$